# Passing a C++ complex array to C

Tags: c++, c

I must pass complex data to a C function from C++. In C++ the data is naturally stored in a 
`std::vector<std::complex> c`. The C function expects the data as an array of double, `double a[]` such that a[0]=Re(c[0]), a[1]=Im(c[0]), a[2]=Re(c[1]), etc.

What is the best safe way to pass such data? Is casting like

```
(double*) (&c[0])
```

asking for trouble?

Sorry if this is duplicate, I could only find information on the related problem of passing C++ complex to C99 complex.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C++0x standard went to lengths to guarantee that such conversions will work (§26.4):

> Moreover, if a is an expression of type `cv std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer expression `i`, then:
>
> — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
>
> — `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

and (§23.3.6):

> The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than bool, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

The layout of the complex value is *not* guaranteed by the prevailing C++03 standard (though the vector layout is), but I would be surprised to find an implementation for which it does not hold.

Comment: Is the C++0x standard already in place? If not, then this guarantee does not necessarily apply to OP (tags are C/C++)

Comment: @Samaursa: I addressed that in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using GNU C which does not comply wiht C++0x by default (at leas the version I'm running), but I may get the behavior you explain (and which would be very handy for me) explicitly requesting C++0x.