# Supply C99 complex arguments from C++

Tags: c++, c, c99

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a C++ complex array to C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020076/passing-a-c-complex-array-to-c)

If a third party C library expects an array of C99 complex numbers as an argument, what is the easiest way to call it from C++, where my complex numbers use the STL complex type? I could just wrap it in a new c function that accepts floats and converts them to complex, but is there a more direct way to do it?

Comment: won't creating that wrapper be a elegant way to do it ?

Comment: Not necessarily the right way, but a special declaration plus a simple pointer cast might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to C99:

> 6.2.5/13 Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array
>   type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is
>   equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex
>   number.

and according to C++11:

> 26.4 if `a` is an expression of type `cv* std::complex<T>*` and the expression `a[i]` is well-deﬁned for an integer expression `i`, then:

- `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and
- `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`

Together, these mean that the two types have the same layout, so you can simply pass the C function a pointer to the array of `std::complex`.

Note that older versions of C++ did not guarantee this layout.

Comment: In C++11 the layout *is* defined to be the same as in C99. See section 26.4.

Comment: I like this answer, though I wish there was a way to do it without copying the data. The array in the code of interest can easily be millions of double precision complex numbers in size. But if the `std::complex` type is not of the same layout, I'll either have to redesign or copy.

Comment: @BoPersson: So it is. I only looked at the class definition, and didn't notice that part of the preamble.

Comment: @Fadecomic: Actually you're in luck: I missed the clause of the C++ standard that specified the layout to be the same as the C types. See the updated answer.