# In memory layout of a C++ complex number

Tags: c++, fft

I am working with a C/C++ FFT library that takes an array of floats as argument. In particular, the routines take an array of 2N floats as argument. I.e., in order to do a N points FFT you pass 2N floats (real and imaginary part of each point).

If I am working with an array of elements of type `std::complex<float>`, can I pass this array as argument to the FFT routines? What's the in memory layout of each element? Two floats or something else? Would it be safe?

Comment: @Mgetz: No, it will always work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5020268/133374).

Comment: So it will always work according to C++11 standard, right?

Comment: @Mgetz: the C++11 standard explicitly guarantees that this kind of access will work (also it is not clear why the compiler should pad an array of a POD class composed by two `float` differently than an array of `float`).

Comment: @Mgetz Please read C++0x standard sections §26.4 and §23.3.6 (you can see quotes of them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020076/passing-a-c-complex-array-to-c)). The standard is worded in such a way that the compiler is *required* to make this work, regardless of padding/alignment requirements.

Comment: @dvnrrs ah... interestingly enough... only for `std::complex` though as best I can tell (at least according to N3337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two `floats`, so you can just cast it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020268/133374).