# Passing big complex arrays from Python to C++ - what's my best option?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, visual-c++

2017/06/13 EDIT:
I tried using boost as was suggested, but after spending more than 3 days trying to get it to compile and link, and failing, I decided that the stupid painful way was probably the fastest and less painfull.... so now my code just saves a mess of gigantic text files (splitting arrays and the complex/ imaginary parts of the numbers across files) that C++ then reads. Elegant... no.... effective... yes.

---

I have some scientific code, currently written in Python, that is being slowed down by a numerical 3d integration step within a loop. To overcome this I am re-writing this particular step in C++. (Cython etc is not an option).

Long story short: I want to transfer several very large arrays of complex numbers from the python code to the C++ integrator as conveniently and painlessly as possible. I could do this manually and painfully using text or binary files - but before I embark on this, I was wondering if I have any better options?

I'm using visual studio for C++ and anaconda for python (not my choice!)

Is there any file format or method that would make it quick and convenient to save an array of complex numbers from python and then recreate it in C++?

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: Why not try to make the algorithm more efficient? If it is inefficient in Python, it will still be in inefficient in C++ (in theory).

Comment: Is doing your integration in Python with Numpy an option? It's quite fast at processing arrays because it uses compiled code rather than the Python interpreter.

Comment: I've tried with Numpy and come to the conclusion that, for me, writing this one step in C++ will ultimately save me time. What I really want is low level memory access and I am finding python/numpy a little opaque in this regard. Maybe it is possible, but I have limited time to get this done, and I have previous experience writing C++ code - so I'd rather just do it this way than spend a lot of time learning to do it in Numpy. Once the data is imported I know what to do in C++.

Comment: @InternetAussie There is no efficiency in python. numpy gains efficiency from being implemented in C, not python. The OP simply wants to exploit the same.

Comment: Also, this step is going to be repeated many hundreds of thousands of times. Any speed increase, even if it is only 20% or something is potentially a big plus. I'm pretty set on using C++. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Ben: So your question is really about "Passing big arrays of complex numbers from Python to C++", right?

Comment: Fair enough. So what's the datatype of your "arrays of complex numbers from the python code"? Are they plain Python lists? If so, Numpy can convert them efficiently to arrays that are contiguous in memory, using either C or Fortran array conventions. And of course it can also do the reverse conversion. So Numpy may be useful for you, even if you don't want to use it for performing the integration.

Comment: I think you're **asking the wrong question**. You *assume* that the solution to your problem is to pass python data to C++, but perhaps (and likely) the solution is to use numpy. I strongly suggest, you ask another question, where you sketch the actual problem, i.e. give an MVCE (in python).

Comment: My arrays are either numpy arrays or mpmath arrays - either way, I can convert them to anything else before they are needed.

Comment: Walter - you may be right, but as it stands, I'm not familiar with all the ins and outs of numpy and I know how to do this in C++, once I have the data. I would like to use C++ so I can know exactly what is going on at the lowest levels, rather than having to study numpy and work out what it's doing behind the scenes.
The C++ part of this is no issue for me. I just want to import the data conveniently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy solution that I used many times is to build your "C++ side" as a dll (=shared object on Linux/OS X), provide a simple, *C-like* entrypoint (straight integers, pointers & co., no STL stuff) and pass the data through `ctypes`.

This avoids boost/SIP/Swig/... build nightmares, can be kept zero-copy (with ctypes you can pass a straight pointer to your numpy data) and allow you to do whatever you want (especially on the build-side - no friggin' distutils, no boost, no nothing - build it with whatever can build a C-like dll) on the C++ side. It has also the nice side-effect of having your C++ algorithm callable from other languages (virtually any language has some way to interface with C libraries).

---

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/ctypes_dll_example)'s a quick artificial example. The C++ side is just:

```
extern "C" {
double sum_it(double *array, int size) {
    double ret = 0.;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        ret += array[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

This has to be compiled to a dll (on Windows) or a `.so` (on Linux), making sure to export the `sum_it` function (automatic with gcc, requires a `.def` file with VC++).

On the Python side, we can have a wrapper like

```
import ctypes
import os
import sys
import numpy as np

path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
cdll = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(path, "summer.dll" if sys.platform.startswith("win") else "summer.so"))
_sum_it = cdll.sum_it
_sum_it.restype = ctypes.c_double

def sum_it(l):
    if isinstance(l, np.ndarray) and l.dtype == np.float64 and len(l.shape)==1:
        # it's already a numpy array with the right features - go zero-copy
        a = l.ctypes.data
    else:
        # it's a list or something else - try to create a copy
        arr_t = ctypes.c_double * len(l)
        a = arr_t(*l)
    return _sum_it(a, len(l))
```

which makes sure that the data is marshaled correctly; then invoking the function is as trivial as

```
import summer
import numpy as np
# from a list (with copy)
print summer.sum_it([1, 2, 3, 4.5])
# from a numpy array of the right type - zero-copy
print summer.sum_it(np.array([3., 4., 5.]))
```

See the [`ctypes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) for more information on how to use it. See also [the relevant documentation in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html).

---

For complex numbers, the situation is slightly more complicated, as there's no builtin for it in ctypes; if we want to use `std::complex<double>` on the C++ side (which is [pretty much guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020268/214671) to work fine with the numpy complex layout, namely a sequence of two doubles), we can write the C++ side as:

```
extern "C" {
std::complex<double> sum_it_cplx(std::complex<double> *array, int size) {
    std::complex<double> ret(0., 0.);
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        ret += array[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

Then, on the Python side, we have to replicate the `c_complex` layout to retrieve the return value (or to be able to build complex arrays without numpy):

```
class c_complex(ctypes.Structure):
    # Complex number, compatible with std::complex layout
    _fields_ = [("real", ctypes.c_double), ("imag", ctypes.c_double)]

    def __init__(self, pycomplex):
        # Init from Python complex
        self.real = pycomplex.real
        self.imag = pycomplex.imag

    def to_complex(self):
        # Convert to Python complex
        return self.real + (1.j) * self.imag
```

Inheriting from `ctypes.Structure` enables the ctypes marshalling magic, which is performed according to the `_fields_` member; the constructor and extra methods are just for ease of use on the Python side.

Then, we have to tell ctypes the return type

```
_sum_it_cplx = cdll.sum_it_cplx
_sum_it_cplx.restype = c_complex
```

and finally write our wrapper, in a similar fashion to the previous one:

```
def sum_it_cplx(l):
    if isinstance(l, np.ndarray) and l.dtype == np.complex and len(l.shape)==1:
        # the numpy array layout for complexes (sequence of two double) is already
        # compatible with std::complex (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020268/214671)
        a = l.ctypes.data
    else:
        # otherwise, try to build our c_complex
        arr_t = c_complex * len(l)
        a = arr_t(*(c_complex(r) for r in l))
    ret = _sum_it_cplx(a, len(l))
    return ret.to_complex()
```

Testing it as above

```
# from a complex list (with copy)
print summer.sum_it_cplx([1. + 0.j, 0 + 1.j, 2 + 2.j])
# from a numpy array of the right type - zero-copy
print summer.sum_it_cplx(np.array([1. + 0.j, 0 + 1.j, 2 + 2.j]))
```

yields the expected results:

```
(3+3j)
(3+3j)
```

Comment: Could you give a simple example (or point to one)? What is `ctypes`?

Comment: @Walter: ctypes is the standard module to interact from Python code with C libraries; see [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). Also, I added a simple example (with compatibility both with regular lists - with the unavoidable copy - and zero-copy compatibility with numpy arrays).

Comment: Glad it worked! Did you obtain the speedup you were after in the end?

Comment: This solution works great for real arrays but it does not answer the question of how to do it starting from complex numpy arrays in python. Any ideas how to this for *complex* arrays?

Comment: @co9olguy: I just updated the example on my git, I'll add it to the question as well.

Comment: @peedurrr: it's actually on Bitbucket - see the first link in the post: https://bitbucket.org/mitalia/ctypes_dll_example

Comment: @MatteoItalia : getting segmentation fault while processing numpy array

Answer (score 6):

I see the OP is over a year old now, but I recently addressed a similar problem using the native Python-C/C++ API and its Numpy-C/C++ extension, and since I personally don't enjoy using ctypes for various reasons (e.g., complex number workarounds, messy code), nor Boost, wanted to post my answer for future searchers.

Documentation for the Python-C API and Numpy-C API are both quite extensive (albeit a little overwhelming at first). But after one or two successes, writing native C/C++ extensions becomes very easy.

Here is an example C++ function that can be called from Python. It integrates a 3D numpy array of either real or complex (`numpy.double` or `numpy.cdouble`) type. The function will be imported through a DLL (`.so`) via the module `cintegrate.so`.

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include <math.h>

static PyObject * integrate3(PyObject * module, PyObject * args)
{
    PyObject * argy=NULL;        // Regular Python/C API
    PyArrayObject * yarr=NULL;   // Extended Numpy/C API
    double dx,dy,dz;

    // "O" format -> read argument as a PyObject type into argy (Python/C API)
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "Oddd", &argy,&dx,&dy,&dz)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Error parsing arguments.");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Determine if it's a complex number array (Numpy/C API)
    int DTYPE = PyArray_ObjectType(argy, NPY_FLOAT); 
    int iscomplex = PyTypeNum_ISCOMPLEX(DTYPE);      

    // parse python object into numpy array (Numpy/C API)
    yarr = (PyArrayObject *)PyArray_FROM_OTF(argy, DTYPE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY);
    if (yarr==NULL) {
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
        return Py_None;
    }

    //just assume this for 3 dimensional array...you can generalize to N dims
    if (PyArray_NDIM(yarr) != 3) {
        Py_CLEAR(yarr);
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected 3 dimensional integrand");
        return NULL;
    }

    npy_intp * dims = PyArray_DIMS(yarr);
    npy_intp i,j,k,m;
    double * p;

    //initialize variable to hold result
    Py_complex result = {.real = 0, .imag = 0};

    if (iscomplex) {
        for (i=0;i<dims[0];i++) 
            for (j=0;j<dims[1];j++) 
                for (k=0;k<dims[1];k++) {
                    p = (double*)PyArray_GETPTR3(yarr, i,j,k);
                    result.real += *p;
                    result.imag += *(p+1);
                }
    } else {
        for (i=0;i<dims[0];i++) 
            for (j=0;j<dims[1];j++) 
                for (k=0;k<dims[1];k++) {
                    p = (double*)PyArray_GETPTR3(yarr, i,j,k);
                    result.real += *p;
                }
    }

    //multiply by step size
    result.real *= (dx*dy*dz);
    result.imag *= (dx*dy*dz);

    Py_CLEAR(yarr);

    //copy result into returnable type with new reference
    if (iscomplex) {
        return Py_BuildValue("D", &result);
    } else {
        return Py_BuildValue("d", result.real);
    }

};
```

Simply put that into a source file (we'll call it `cintegrate.cxx` along with the module definition stuff, inserted at the bottom:

```
static PyMethodDef cintegrate_Methods[] = {
    {"integrate3",  integrate3, METH_VARARGS,
     "Pass 3D numpy array (double or complex) and dx,dy,dz step size. Returns Reimman integral"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};


static struct PyModuleDef module = {
   PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
   "cintegrate",   /* name of module */
   NULL, /* module documentation, may be NULL */
   -1,       /* size of per-interpreter state of the module,
                or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
   cintegrate_Methods
};
```

Then compile that via `setup.py` much like Walter's boost example with just a couple obvious changes- replacing `file.cc` there with our file `cintegrate.cxx`, removing boost dependencies, and making sure the path to `"numpy/arrayobject.h"` is included.

In python then you can use it like:

```
import cintegrate
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(4,8,16) + 1j*np.random.randn(4,8,16)

# arbitrary step size dx = 1., y=0.5, dz = 0.25
ans = cintegrate.integrate3(arr, 1.0, 0.5, .25)
```

This specific code hasn't been tested but is mostly copied from working code.

Comment: If you get segmentation fault, you might need to add `import_array();` before `int DTYPE = PyArray_ObjectType(argy, NPY_FLOAT); `
(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66245936)

Answer (score 1):

**Note added in edit.**
As mentioned in the comments, `python` itself, being an interpreted language, has little potential for computational efficiency. So in order to make python scripts efficient, one must use modules which aren't all interpreted, but under the hood call compiled (and optimized) code written in, say, C/C++. This is exactly what `numpy` does for you, in particular for operations on whole arrays.

Therefore, the first step towards efficient python scripts is the usage of `numpy`. Only the second step is to try to use your own compiled (and optimized) code. Therefore, I have assumed in my example below that you were using `numpy` to store the array of complex numbers. Everything else would be ill-advised.

---

There are various ways in which you can access python's original data from within a C/C++ program. I personally have done this with [boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html), but must warn you that the documentation and support are lousy at best: you're pretty much on your own (and stack overflow, of course).

For example your C++ file may look like this

```
// file.cc
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

namespace p = boost::python;
namespace n = p::numpy;

n::ndarray func(const n::ndarray&input, double control_variable)
{
  /* 
     your code here, see documentation for boost python
     you pass almost any python variable, doesn't have to be numpy stuff
  */
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module_name)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  n::initialize();   // only needed if you use numpy in the interface
  p::def("function", func, "doc-string");
}
```

to compile this, you may use a python script such as

```
# setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

module_name = Extension(
    'module_name',
    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11','-stdlib=libc++','-I/some/path/','-march=native'],
    extra_link_args=['-stdlib=libc++'],
    sources=['file.cc'],
    libraries=['boost_python','boost_numpy'])

setup(
    name='module_name',
    version='0.1',
    ext_modules=[module_name])
```

and run it as `python setup.py build`, which will create an appropriate `.so` file in a sub-directory of `build`, which you can import from python.

Comment: @martineau why not?

Comment: My comment was before you edited it—obviously,wise guy.

Comment: Note that this answer assumes that the input are ndarrays, which OP explicitly said are not (well, OP said they aren't using numpy).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I assume nothing. I merely demonstrate how one may pass data from python to C++, exemplifying with an `numpy.ndarray`, but that is only an example. However, the OP would be daft to not use a `numpy.ndarray`. Note also that the OP does not mention numpy and the comment made does not imply that numpy arrays are not used.

Comment: I am using numpy!
I've just found it to be a little slow - or perhaps I should say hard (for me with my current knowledge) to optimise. This is why I would rather use C++.

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution now.

Comment: I had to give up on this. Compiling boost was a nightmare, and even when I managed that, my code wouldnt compile without errors. I gave up after three days and just resorted to a million horrible text files. Thanks for the tip about boost though - I may come back to it for future projects where I'm not stuck using visual studio